# Dynamic XPath- Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have the following dynamic xpath:

```
/html/body[@class='modal-open']/div[@class='container']/form[@id='form_application']/div[@id='interviewContent']/div[@class='modal-dialog']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='modal-body']/div[@id='form_application:interviewContent']/div[@id='form_application:questionDropdown']/select[@id='form_application:j_idt473']
```

How can I make this unique for Selenium Web Driver? I was going to do a Starts-with method but this is pertaining to a drop down box  where the values selected changes with each log in.

Page Source:

```
<br /><select id="form_application:j_idt473" name="form_application:j_idt473" class="form-control" size="1" style="width:250px;display:inline" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change','@this','form_application:questionDropdown form_application:dropdown_interview')">  <option value=""></option>
<option value="02">Alaska</option>
<option value="01">Alabama</option>
<option value="05">Arkansas</option>
<option value="60">American Samoa</option>
<option value="04" selected="selected">Arizona</option>
<option value="06">California</option>
""""
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, or what it is you want. Do you want to select an item from the dropdown? For your test, do you know what the value is going to be?

Comment: I get what you're trying to do, but to give you a proper answer, I need to see the page source.  Your second select object will not likely be present until the value in the first select is set.  Since your ID's are dynamically generated, you'll need to use other methods to create a locator, but we'll need to see the page source as you have the screen shot above first.

Comment: Seeing that you're new, if you add the page source, please add it to the original post (edit) and not in comments, thanks.

Comment: The name and id are dynamic-

Comment: try this css selector: div[id*='questionDropdown'] > select, if there is only one dropdown inside div[@id='form_application:questionDropdown']

Comment: Which Selenium binding are you using `Java` or `Python` or `NodeJS` or `C#` or `Ruby`

Comment: This is Java-   I am going to try the css selector and start-with method to see if either of those work-  thank you for all you comments-

Answer (score 0):

You can use css attribute selectors to match partial strings. I would get rid of that super complex xpath and use a contains selector instead to match a substring. Something like this should do the trick...

```
select[onchange*="form_application:questionDropdown form_application:dropdown_interview"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your Question that the **`xpath`** is dynamic and the **`HTML`** clearly shows the element as a **`<select>`** tag so we have to construct our **`xpath`** accordingly. I think you were quite right when you spoke about using `Starts-with method` as looking at the **`id`** and **`name`** attributes it seems to me though the attributes are dynamic but the **`string`** **`form_application:`** will be a **`constant`**. So we can use the following `xpath` :

### Java

```
Select city = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control' and starts-with(@id,'form_application:')]")));
city.selectByIndex(2);
```

### Python

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='form-control' and starts-with(@id,'form_application:')]"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Alabama")
```